# Is it possible to pay to stay at a scouting campsite in the UK?

Tags: uk, accommodation, camping

There are a lot of scouting campsites in the UK, some that list quite reasonable rates for an overnight stay while backpacking or cycle touring. However, are these only available to large groups, scouting affiliates or can just anyone make a booking?

Comment: Do you realize that most of these sites are booked by huge groups with mostly young people, where they do not keep quiet for separate visitors and where they do not like strangers who are not checked out for work with children.

Comment: Yes, I realise that, and it is an unusual place to stay, but none of that prohibits  actually staying there.

Comment: Do you have the clearance to work with children? (It might make a difference whether they do allow you to book?)

Comment: If you are a big group, it's sometimes possible. You'd have to contact the site directly.  As an individual, it's highly unlikely - they tend to be either nearly full of kids or locked up and unattended

Answer (score 2):

Scouting campsites can be run by local groups or by bigger regions or national scouting organizations or by commercial camp sites.

There are no national or international rules whether campsites not used by groups can be made available to individual guests.

In the UK (and many other countries) there are rules about whom is allowed to work or even be with children. If you do not have the right paperwork for that you will/should not be allowed to stay on a scouting site when there are children or young people on site.

Scouting sites without groups visiting are mostly closed (and locked).

But you can try contacting the owner/manager in advance. Walk-ins are very unlikely.

I have been active as a scout leader in the Netherlands and I am friends with a lot of people involved with Scouting in the UK.
I have seen people who after a group using a campsite were allowed to stay a bit longer, but only after having met the manager of the site while there with the group. There were no young people on that site at the time.
It is possible at times but it is very unlikely.

Comment: I spot checked a couple of the campsites on the Scouting list. Some would accept church and youth groups not affiliated with Scouting but none accepted individuals.